# C# loading data from MS Access database to listbox

Tags: c#

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection();
    OleDbDataReader dr;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\AsusK450c\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\ADD\ADD\testing.accdb;Persist Security Info=True";
        cmd.Connection = cn;
        loaddata();

    }
    private void loaddata()
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        listBox2.Items.Clear();
        try
        {
            string q = "select * from info";
            cmd.CommandText = q;
            cn.Open();
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString());
                    listBox2.Items.Add(dr[1].ToString());
                }
            }
            dr.Close();
            cn.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            cn.Close();
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

This is an image of the database:
[image]

[image]

I added 2 list boxes. Those two should display the data i put in the database but It doesn't. I don't know which is wrong, the path, the code or the database

Comment: what issues you are facing?

Comment: I added 2 list boxes. Those two should display the data i put in the database but It doesnt

Comment: do you get an exception?

Comment: Can you debug and check `dr` contains values or it getting any exception

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with you code. Check if you are getting any exceptions or pointed to the right database.

Also check if you have assigned the function **Form1_Load()** to form's load event

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your problem is, but you can change the connectionString by this way:

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionStringBuilder builder = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionStringBuilder();
            builder.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0";
            builder.OleDbServices = -1;
            builder.DataSource = @"C:\Users\AsusK450c\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\ADD\ADD\testing.accdb";
            cn.ConnectionString = builder.ConnectionString;
```

`OleDbServices = -1` can help you.